# How can I use "home" state within "global" reducer?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga, immutable.js

I have a react, redux-saga, immutable js app.

With this architecture, my redux store is like this.

```
global: {
   notifications:{...}
   ...
},
home: {
   ...contents
}
```

The problem is when I want to update `home contents` i am using a reducer attached to the home. But inside the home reducer, `notifications` is not available.
Because `notifications` is inside `global`.

Just the opposite of this approach is using the `global` reducer, notifications are available at the global state. But this time I can not access the `home > contents`

My code is below.

This is the reducer attached to global:

```
case CONTENT_ADD_SUCCESS:
  return state
    .set('loading', false)
    .update('notifications', arr => arr.push(
      fromJS(
      {
        show: true,
        type: 'success',
        message: action.response.message,
      }
    )
   .setIn(['home', 'contents'], action.response.newContent)
  ))
```

Global Reducer Injection

```
const withReducer = injectReducer({ key: 'global', reducer });
const withSaga = injectSaga({ key: 'global', saga });

export default compose(
  withReducer,
  withSaga,
  withConnect,
)(withStyles(mainLayoutStyle)(MainLayout));
```

How can I use different reducer states? For this example, I want to access global notifications and also update home content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't know that I can use the same constant for different reducers.

Basically I attached another reducer, a home reducer to the same constant.

Below is my code:
This is for `layout reducer.` managing notifications with `CONTENT_ADD_SUCCESS`

```
case CONTENT_ADD_SUCCESS:
        return state
            .set('loading', false)
            .update('notifications', arr => arr.push(
                fromJS(
                    {
                        key: CONTENT_ADD_SUCCESS_N_ID,
                        show: true,
                        type: 'success',
                        message: action.response.message,
                    }
                )
            ))
```

This one for `home reducer` managing home contents with `CONTENT_ADD_SUCCESS`

```
case CONTENT_ADD_SUCCESS:
        console.log('HOME REDUCER :: CONTENT_ADD_SUCCESS', state);
        return state
          .update('contents', arr => arr.unshift(fromJS(JSON.parse(action.response.newContent))))
```